# Streaming data from Kafka into Cassandra in real time

Tags: cassandra, apache-kafka

What's the best way to write date from Kafka into Cassandra? I would expect it to be a solved problem, but there doesn't seem to be a standard adapter. 
A lot of people seem to be using Storm to read from Kafka and then write to Cassandra, but storm seems like somewhat of an overkill for simple ETL operations.

Comment: Just as an update - We went with Spark Streaming at so far so good. Testing DataStax Spark now

Comment: Also, Kafka 3.0 is going to have Kafka Connect - a framework for building connectors. Eventually they will probably have a C* connector too. As I noted before, Spark Streaming has being working really well for us. Easy to use, and it takes care of fault tolerance and scalability for you.

Answer (score 5):

We are heavily using Kafka and Cassandra through Storm

We rely on Storm because:

- there are usually a lot of distributed processing (inter-node) steps before result of original message hit Cassandra (Storm bolt topologies)
- We don't need to maintain consumer state of Kafka (offset) ourselves - Storm-Kafka connector is doing it for us when all products of original message is acked within Storm
- Message processing is distributed across nodes with Storm natively

Otherwise if it is a very simple case, you might effectively read messages from Kafka and write result to Cassandra without help of Storm

Comment: Thanks! Where does Storm persists the Kafka offset? Can you guarantee exactly once message processing if the offset is not stored in the same transaction as the processed data in Cassandra? Also, have you guys looked into Spark Streaming?

Comment: In our particular case it is "at-least-one" guarantee. It is fine - we designed most of our processing operations as idempotent. I heard about `exactly-once` guarantees in Storm Trident, but it is a micro-batching, so is Spark Streaming.

Answer (score 1):

Recent release of Kafka came with the connector concept to support source and sinks as first class concepts in the design. With this, you do not need any streaming framework for moving data in/out of Kafka. Here is the Cassandra connector for Kafka that you can use: https://github.com/tuplejump/kafka-connect-cassandra